# Explicit expressions of inner / outer automorphism of symplectic group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, automorphism-group

We know that one may identify the automorphism group of the Dynkin diagram of G with a subgroup of Out(G).

In this way, the outer automorphism of symplectic group $Sp(n)$ (some people may denote it as $Sp(2n)$) is related to the Dynkin diagrams $C_{n}$. We use the convention:

$$Sp(1)=SU(2)=Spin(3)=C_1$$

$$Sp(2)=Spin(5)=C_2$$

> Question 1 (Examples):

- $Sp(1)=SU(2)$ has only an SO(3) ($\supseteq \mathbb{Z}_2$)-inner automorphism, inner automorphism, but no outer automorphism (because no symmetry for Dynkin diagram $C_1$). Is this true?
- [$Sp(2)=Spin(5)=C_{5}$ seems not to have any outer automorphism](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199662920.001.0001/acprof-9780199662920-chapter-8) (because no symmetry for Dynkin diagram $C_5$).
- For a general $Sp(n)$, do we have any inner automorphism, but no outer automorphism?

> Question 2:
>   Are there some nice expressions we can write for the mapping
>
> - inner automorphism

How do we find the explicit $k$ such that
$$
k g_{{Sp(n)}} k^{-1} = g_{{Sp(n)}}^{'}?
$$
which is the inner automorphism arisen by the conjugation of $k \in Sp(n)$?

> - outer automorphism

Look at the symmetries of Dynkin diagram $C_n$, it looks that there is NO any outer automorphism. Is this true? Alternatively, if it is false, how do we find the explicit map
$$
 g_{{Sp(n)}} \to g_{{Sp(n)}}^{'}?
$$
which explicit map is the outer automorphism?